# genymotion interface inverted

Tags: android, genymotion

since I cannot use the android studio emulator , I tried to install this genymotion but the interface is inverted or upside down. I tried to reinstall and reboot my computer but the thing still inverted. Any Idea or did some one encounter this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCxJO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DVJT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Genymation is based on virtualbox, you can view the configuration directly in virtualbox to check whether it is normal

Comment: the fonts in login page is messed up. I haven't able to login yet to open the genymotion. I'm still outside the login